# why the result of the argument is copied to a local variable?

Tags: c, output

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <conio.h>

   int a();

   void b();

   int main()
   {
       b(a());
       return 0;
   }
   int a()
   {
       return 5;
   } 
   void b()
   {
        int   x;
        printf("%d",x);
   }
```

'x' is not the argument of function b then why the result of function a is copie to x?
why the output of this program is 5?

Comment: it's not that it's 'copied' to x.

Comment: This has something to do with variadic arguments. Don't remember what exactly. There was a similar question yesterday. Will link it once I get it

Comment: Isn't this just printf uninitialized variable?

Answer (score 0):

Passing argument to a function that accept no arguments is an Undefined Bihaviour. And if you try to change your `b()` definition to this below it will generate an error since it doesn't accept any argument: [Live Demo](https://eval.in/84824)

```
void b(void)
{
    int   x;
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

And it's obvious that it doesn't print `5`: [Live Demo](https://eval.in/84823)

When your function `b()` calls `printf` it will print the value stored in the address allocated by the variable `x`. And since you didn't inisialize `x` and you didn't change it's value during the call of `b()` it clould print anything. it's just occasionaly printed `5` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you are printing is uninitialized. So it may print `5` but it also may print something very else.

This question is also somewhat related to [C/C++: Calling function with no arguments with function which returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143906/c-c-curious-question-about-calling-function-with-no-arguments-with-function-w) because of

```
b(a());
```